# hive sql:invalid column reference ‘2’

Tags: sql, hive

my hive sql:

```
select id from Table
where date>'20180101'
and date<'20190101'
group by id
having count(distinct substr(date,5,2))=7
```

and return an error:invalid column reference ‘2’

why and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below,

Query expects aggregation function to be part of select clause.

```
with table1 as (select 1 as id, '20180101' as date1 union select 1 as id, '20110101' as date1 union select 1 as id, '20190101' as date1 union select 2 as id, '20180101' as date1 union select 3 as id, '20180102' date1) select id, count(distinct substr(date1,5,2)) from table1 where date1>'20180101' and date1<'20190101' group by id having count(distinct substr(date1,5,2))=7;
```

Below query works -
We can have aggregation function only in having clause, but it has to be only count(*)

```
select id from table1 where date1>'20180101' and date1<'20190101' group by id having count(date1)=7;
```

But below query throws error -

```
 select id from table1 where date1>'20180101' and date1<'20190101' group by id having count(distinct (date1))=7;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:319 Invalid column reference 'date1'
```

Hope this helps